# Buffered image in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

How to display buffered image in vaadin?

I want to display buffered image in image view with vaadin.

So , I followed this [Tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-resources.html#application.resources.stream) from vaadin site .But, it not done.

main.java

```
package com.example;


import com.vaadin.server.StreamResource;
import com.vaadin.server.StreamResource.StreamSource;
import com.vaadin.ui.Layout;





public class MainView {



public MainView()   {

// Create an instance of our stream source.
StreamSource imagesource = new MyImageSource();

// Create a resource that uses the stream source and give it
// a name. The constructor will automatically register the
// resource in the application.
StreamResource resource =
    new StreamResource(imagesource, "myimage.png");

// Create an image component that gets its contents
// from the resource.
Layout.addComponent(new Image("Image title", resource);
}
}
```

MyImageSource.java

```
package com.example;

import com.vaadin.server.StreamResource.StreamSource;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MyImageSource implements StreamSource {
ByteArrayOutputStream imagebuffer = null;
int reloads = 0;

// This method generates the stream contents
public InputStream getStream () {
    // Create an image
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage (400, 400,
                              BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D drawable = image.createGraphics();

    // Draw something static
    drawable.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    drawable.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    drawable.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    drawable.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    drawable.drawOval(50, 50, 300, 300);

    // Draw something dynamic
    drawable.setFont(new Font("Montserrat",
                              Font.PLAIN, 48));
    drawable.drawString("Reloads=" + reloads, 75, 216);
    reloads++;
    drawable.setColor(new Color(0, 165, 235));
    int x= (int) (200-10 + 150*Math.sin(reloads * 0.3));
    int y= (int) (200-10 + 150*Math.cos(reloads * 0.3));
    drawable.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);

    try {
        // Write the image to a buffer
        imagebuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", imagebuffer);

        // Return a stream from the buffer
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(
            imagebuffer.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b61E1.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my.vaadin.app</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>app</name>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>8.0.5</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>8.0.5</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- If there are no local customisations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
    <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/styles.css</include>
                            <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
            running jetty:run on the command line. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
        <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have lot of problems in newer version . so , I now I goes to older version.

But, I have error in image layout. how can i solve this?

Comment: `com.example.MyImageSource cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.server.InputStreamFactory`

Comment: Note that the tutorial you linked is for Vaadin 8. The StreamResource API has changed since then, and based on your code snippet you're using Vaadin 10 or later. Here's the link to the corresponding docs for Vaadin 14: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content.html#using-code-streamresource-code

Comment: What version of Vaadin are your using?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. In your browser you're accessing `localhost:8080/calling-java-from-javascript`, which does not match the route you have defined. When you have a `@Route` annotation on a view named `Main`, it will be mapped to the root URL, so **try accessing it with just `localhost:8080`.**
2. I'm not sure about the purpose of your `add` method, in which you throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. I assume it's generated by your IDE, but you're extending `VerticalLayout` which already has an `add` method, so **remove your version of the `add` method**.

**Edit to answer your next issue**

Your last error message says

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.MyImageSource cannot be cast to com.vaadin.flow.server.InputStreamFactory`

You can't cast `MyImageSource` to an `InputStreamFactory`, because it isn't an `InputStreamFactory`.

You can make it one, though. All you have to do is to

1. Change `extends StreamSource` to `implements InputStreamFactory`
2. Change `public InputStream getStream ()` to `public InputStream createInputStream()`

Comment: I followed the above two things. But, it not done. I edited my question.

Comment: Edited my answer